# How can I tell which of my tag-wiki edits are rejected, and why?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-wikis

I put some work into improving a bunch of tag wiki excerpts. Many of the were approved. But, today, I went to add something to distinguish between [sun](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sun) and [sunlight](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunlight) (the former for images *of* the sun or where the sun is directly involved), and got a harsh white page with

> Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.

Which kind of sucks in several ways. First, I don't think any of my edits were *awful*, although I won't claim any sort of perfection. Mostly they were on tags which did not actually *have* a wiki before — and a whole bunch of them were accepted. And second, blocked for 7 days? Harsh.

I'm not just *complaining* that I got knocked down, here — I'd like to see a list of rejected edits, so I can fix whatever was wrong.

Comment: I believe  that the answer should provide a way to view your tag-wiki edits

Comment: @Akram — yes. The UI is better than it was a year ago. :)

Comment: yes but still the answer doesn't say how to check your tag-wiki edits, need to post a new question perhaps?

Comment: @Akram http://photo.stackexchange.com/users/6236/akram-mellice?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: yeah now I can see who's rejecting my edits ;-)

Comment: @Akram — hopefully with constructive commentary. :)

Comment: sure I understand your point :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI is kind of sucky, but you can see your stats on each of your edits.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/97

look at the bottom.

It seems 5 of your suggested edits were rejected, you can see who rejected them in the list.

Personally I do not find anything very wrong with your edits, and am not against raising thresholds. The reason we are so harsh is that we need to defend our queue from flooding.

If you would like the thresholds changed somehow, please raise an item on meta.stackoverflow.com cause it would be a global change.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the UI only shows the last handful of my suggested edits. I'll raise something on meta-stackoverflow.

Comment: @mattdm all are browsable try clicking on the ones at the bottom of the list ... the UI is kind of crappy ... I really need to fix it.

Comment: Oh, I get it. That really _is_ crappy. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85187/can-the-wiki-edit-reject-algorithm-be-softened

Comment: @SamSaffron can you tell me how to get my list of edits? I don't want to repeat the question but I can't find a way to get my edits

Comment: @AkramMellice your profile -> activity -> revisions